# Java having a concurrent reservation's refund method

Tags: java, mysql, concurrency, locking, payment

I'm building a small java API that will handle some basic financial transaction (charge, refund etc...).

I'm having some trouble getting the refund system efficient and concurrent problem free.

I have a Mysql DB with a table that looks like this:

```
Reservation:
user_id
status (can be ACCEPTED,CANCELED,DECLINED or PENDING)
total_price


@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public synchronised void refund() {
    Reservation reservation = reservationDao.get(id, userId);
    // We only allow a refund in case the restoration was accepted (which means paid)
    if (ACCEPTED.reservation.getStatus()) {
      //1) execute a NON REVERSIBLE refund using my payment processor API
      paymementProcess.refund(amount);

      // 2) save new status to DB
      reservation.setStatus(CANCELED);
      reservationDao.update(reservation);  
    }
}
```

the condition 1) and 2) kind of 'need' to be atomic, because I cannot allow a thread_1 to execute 1) (without yet having executed 2) and then a thread_2 comes in and because thread_1 didn't execute 2) will pass the if condition and call 1) as well...

This is why 'for now' I have set the refund method synchronised but this is quite bad because it only allow 1 refund at a time...

I'm not very happy with this because I could probably with no problem refund multiple "different reservation"  at the same time. 
I just need to make sure that 1) is done ONCE and only ONCE per reservation. and ONLY when the reservation status is ACCEPTED.

Could someone point me in the right direction to archive this ? Is there some locking mechanism I could put in place?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set/configure the *Isolation Level* for the transaction. For MySql InnoDb, the default isolation level is *REPEATABLE_READ*, which should be ok for your case.

You didn't mention in which context this code is executing (JEE, Spring, other), so I cannot tell you how to explicitly control the isolation level. However, there are lots of information on this topic out there.

**Update**

*REPEATABLE_READ* means that a transaction will see the same value for a set of rows for every select, which means that no other transaction can update or delete any row from that set.

Looking more closely on your example, you should make sure that the

```
reservationDAO.get()
```

method issues a

```
SELECT ... FROM ... FOR UPDATE
```

That should prevent other transactions to read that row until the first tx   ends.

Comment: My webapp is using Spring

Comment: Ok, then I believe you can specify the isolation level as an annotation attribute

Comment: Yep, but what how does setting the isolation  would some the problem of avoiding the 1) to be execute twice ?